# Use coldfusion to get x number of words total including keyword

Tags: coldfusion, cpu-word, coldfusion-8

Okay this is part of my search results project, in it, I have description being returned from multiple tables. All of that part works 100%.

I currently use a trim_text function, which I pass a string, and how many words I want to keep.

However, now I need to modify it to make sure the keyword/search term is in the returning description to help show the validity of that in the search results.

Here below is the existing trim_text function, that I need your help to modify.

```
<cffunction name="trim_text" output="false" access="remote" returntype="string">
    <cfargument name="string" type="string" required="true">
    <cfargument name="word_limit" type="integer" required="false">

    <cfparam name="word_limit" default=20>
    <cfparam name="snippet" default="">
    <cfparam name="return_string" default="">
    <cfset return_string = "">

    <cfset return_string = reReplace( string, "</?\w+(\s*[\w:]+\s*=\s*(""[^""]*""|'[^']*'))*\s*/?>", " ", "all" ) />
    <cfset return_string = reReplace( trim( return_string ), "\s+", " ", "all" ) />

    <cfset snippet = reMatch( "([^\s]+\s?){1,#word_limit#}", return_string ) />

    <cfif !arrayLen( snippet )>
        <cfreturn "" />
    </cfif>

    <cfset charCount = listlen(snippet[1]) />
    <cfset wordCount = ( (word_limit * (arrayLen( snippet ) - 1)) + listLen( snippet[ arrayLen( snippet ) ], " " ) ) />

    <cfif charCount gt 190>
        <cfreturn left(snippet[1],190) & "..." />
    </cfif>

    <cfset return_string = snippet[1] & "..." />

    <cfreturn return_string />

</cffunction>
```

So my end goal is a description that contains the keyword.

So for example.

Let us say I am searching for the keyword 'business'

And I get the correct search result, however the description doesn't have that word in the description shown, since we are limiting the description to 25 words, via the trim_text function. It makes all the descriptions look similar in size. But doesn't help prove the validity of results where the keyword is further down in the description.

Any questions? I hope I made this very clear.

I am using Coldfusion 8 Standard. I am testing this on my development server.

Thank You...

Comment: Why aren't you using built-in CF search to do this?

Comment: @crosenblum: if you index information using `<cfindex/>` you could can search and context highlight results with `<cfsearch/>`.

Comment: I would almost never use a verity search, I'd rather either use sql queries, or the fulltext catalog's, which gives me far more control of what get's searched.

Comment: I am not asking what is the optimal search solution, I just want a modified function to get 25 words of text that include a keyword, even if the keyword isn't in the first 25 words of text. If you can help with that, awesome if not, that's okay.

Comment: No thanks, not interested in a different search solution, just want to get help fixing/improving the function above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to find the position of the keyword in the string, and then take the characters either side.

Treat your string as a list, and use whitespace characters and punction as the delimters.

Something like this:

`<cfset wordFoundPos = listFindNoCase(string, searchTerm, " ,.-:;") />`

Say that returns 42 - that is, the searchTerm is the 42nd word.

Convert that to a character position like so:

`<cfset charPos = findnocase(1, string, searchTerm) />`

Then grab the characters either side of that character:

`<cfset context = mid(190, charPos-90, string) />`

You'll need to detect when the searchterm is found too close to the start or end of the string to avoide errors, and to work out when to append and/or prepend ellipses to the context.

Comment: Nice answer. Was working on something similar to that, but I had a feeling i'd need some kind of string expert or regex expert to get an error-free results. I will try this approach..